# Why can I not perform this split in probablity?

Tags: probability

> From the letters of *WOOLLOOMOOLOO* (a real place in Australia!) 4
>   random letters are chosen. Find probability of 4 O's chosen if at
>   least 3 O's have been chosen

In the question above, I tried to split the probability into 2 cases, ie when there has been 3 O's chosen and 4 O's chosen. 
$$=P(4O|3O) + P(4O|4O)$$
I understand that this immediately is wrong (the second term evaluates to 1 which means the overall probability is greater than 1!). But what I don't understand is WHY I cannot do this split. It seems normal and intuitive to do this because I'm taking all the possible cases right? Can someone provide an explanation (preferably an intuitive one) of why it's not ok?

Comment: Chosen how? Is there replacement or do the four letters have to be different?

Comment: sorry, the letters are chosen without replacement

Comment: I suspect you want $P(4O \mid 3O \text{ or } 4O) = \dfrac{P(4O)}{P(3O) + P(4O)}$.  I do not see what your expression (which seems to evaluate to $0+1=1$) is based on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability is finicky in that you need to be careful with what your events mean. For instance, if
$$3O = \{\text{I chose three Os}\},$$
and
$$ 4O = \{\text{I chose four Os}\};$$
then $P(4O|3O) = 0,$ because if I chose 4 Os I cannot have chosen 3 Os; for the same reason, $P(3O|4O) = 0$.

How to reason about this then? You change perspective.

### Squential draws

If the four letters drawn have to be different, then I am choosing 4 letters among 13 of which 8 are Os. I know that three of the letters chosen are Os; this leaves me with   5 Os in 10 letters. Hence, the probability of drawing a 4th O after a series of 3 Os is
$$P(O_4 | O_1, O_2, O_3) = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2};$$
where $O_j$ is the event
$$ O_j = \{\text{the $j$th letter drawn is an O}\}.$$

### Bag draws

Suppose instead we draw 4 letters all at once and define the event
$$N_j = \{\text{I see $j$ Os}\}.$$
Then, the probability we are looking for is $P(N_4|N_3)$. Again we can use counting and say that the probability is given by
$$ P(N_4|N_3) = \frac{\# \text{ of ways to draw 4 Os}}{\#\text{ of ways of drawing 3 Os} + \# \text{ of ways of drawing 4 Os}};$$
where
$$ \# \text{ of ways to draw 4 Os} = { 13 \choose 4},$$
and
$$ \# \text{ of ways of drawing 4 Os} = {8 \choose 3}{5\choose 1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be $P(4O|3O).P(3O)+P(4O|4O).P(4O)$ if the letters are chosen without replacement.

Comment: Why is that not $0 . P(3O)+1. P(4O) = P(4O)$ when you want the rather larger $P(4O \mid 3O \text{ or } 4O)$?

Comment: thanks but could you explain why?

Comment: My answer is based on the total probability formula. The event $\{$ at least 3 O are chosen$\}$ = $\{3 O\}  \cup \{4 O\}$. $P(4 O|3 O)=\frac{5}{10}$, $P(3 O)=\frac{C_8^3C_5^1}{C_{13}^4}$. $P(4 O|4 O)=1$, $P(4 O)=\frac{C_8^4}{C_{13}^4}$.